# Converting python code into a function

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to convert the code below into a function, but keep getting errors. Can anyone help with the steps I need to take in order to refactor this code into a funtion?

```
n1 = int(input('Enter First Number')) 
n2 = int(input('Enter Second Number'))
n3 = int(input('Enter Third Number')) 

average = int(n1 + n2 + n3)/3          

print('')
print('The Average Is:'),
print(average)
```

Comment: What are the "returning errors"?

Comment: Also, how did you try to convert it into function? Show us the code that didn't work.

Comment: Also, what part do you _want_ to convert into a function? Inputing the data and averaging it? Both of those, plus outputting the answer? Some other subset of the functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way.

```
def calculate_average():

    n1 = int(input('Enter First Number')) 
    n2 = int(input('Enter Second Number'))
    n3 = int(input('Enter Third Number')) 

    return int(n1 + n2 + n3)/3          

average = calculate_average()

print('')
print('The Average Is:')
print(average)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, one simple way is as follows:

```
def calculate_average(x, y, z):
    l = [x, y, z]
    return int(sum(l)/len(l))
```

If you would like the function to be agnostic to the length of the list of numbers, you can pass the list in as the function argument like so:

```
def calculate_average(l):
    # pass in list of numbers
    return int(sum(l)/len(l))
```

You would call this function like this: calculate_average([n1, n2, n3])

You could also do a single line by importing statics (as suggested below) or numpy and using the mean function.

```
import numpy
numpy.mean([n1, n2, n3])

import statistics
statistics.mean([n1, n2, n3])
```

There's likely 10 other ways to do this.  Thanks peanut gallery and Happy averaging/meaning!!

Comment: I really think we should not encourage users to import numpy for something as simple as averaging.

Comment: Agree, hence the multiple solutions!  thx

Comment: If you're going to give multiple solutions, why include numpy, but not the `statistics.mean` function that's in the stdlib? That way you can take any iterable instead of only a sequence, and your code will work even if you throw huge numbers and tiny numbers into the mix, and so on.